# Fixed div position with controls on the bottom until window is scrolled to its original place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a form with long list of fields. So I want to see `Submit` allways on the bottom. And it should be there till I scroll to its original position.

I've tried to do a sample:

> http://jsfiddle.net/kSpjh/2/

But the code is ugly and ther is an issue that gray panel should be 100% till scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kSpjh/4/

using `left: 10px; right: 10px;` for `#sticker`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you think is so ugly about the code. I didn't look at it in depth, but it's pretty short, so I can't imagine it's that poorly constructed.

Beyond that, is the only other issue that you want the background of #sticker to extend across the full length of the screen? In that case, just give it a width:100% in the CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/kSpjh/5/

But you also said that it "should be 100% till scrolling", so does that mean you want it to contract to the smaller size once scrolling begins? If so, you should put the width:100% in the $(document).ready() function, so that you can then remove it as a result of the .scroll() event:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/kSpjh/7/